# Can't import React Bootstrap component in react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

I want to use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) in my mobile app.

But when I write :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from 'react-native'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export default class Register extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.main_container}>
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                ...
```

I have this error :

> Invariant Violation: View config not found name input. Make sur to start component names with a capital letter.

This is same problem for `Form.Label` component (and I think for all the components [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/))

Comment: i guess its not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Bootstrap is not working in react native.you can use open source kits available for react native 
like

1. [react-native-material-kit](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit)
2. [NativeBase kit for react native](https://nativebase.io/)
3. [galio react native kit](https://galio.io/)

etc

Answer (score 0):

Check these UI libraries for React native development, React-bootstrap is dedicated for Reactjs Web development not mobile dev:

**[awesome-reactnative-ui](https://github.com/madhavanmalolan/awesome-reactnative-ui)**

Answer (score 0):

Similar intentions lead me to creation of this package:
https://github.com/andrenerd/react-native-bootstrap-styles

It generates Bootstrap like styles, that can be used in a pretty straightforward manner:

```
import BootstrapStyleSheet from 'react-native-bootstrap-styles';

const bootstrapStyleSheet = new BootstrapStyleSheet();
const {styles: s, constants: c} = bootstrapStyleSheet;

class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[s.container, s.h100, s.justifyContentCenter]}>
        <Text style={[s.text, s.textPrimary, s.myXs1]}>Hello world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must try to import each bootstrap component as below, I hope it will help you out.

```js
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Checkbox, Radio, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
```